# Why Browse packages in Sublime Text 3 opens a folder with the a User folder inside?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I just got a new computer, installed Sublime Text 3 and I want to start installing new packages, when I go to `cmd+shift+p` and typed `Package` or `Install` it doesn't return anything similar as in Sublime Text 2, what should I do in order to just open Install Packages and start typing the name of the packages I want in order to install them in Sublime?

The User folder contains this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title and body of your question refer to two completely different things. The folder you reference in the title is the `Packages` Folder, opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** (which is under the **`Sublime Text`** menu on OS X). Initially, `Packages` only contains the `User` folder, which is where, surprisingly, user files are stored, such as your user preferences.

The reason you can't install packages right away is because you need to [install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3). Follow the directions carefully, restart Sublime when asked to, and you'll be ready to install plugins, themes, color schemes, and other packages.